# Subset columns based on sum of rows

Tags: r, syntax, subset

I would like to subset the `df` columns based on sum of rows.

`df` dataframe:

```
NE001  NE002  NE003  NE004
  2      0      0      2
```

My expected output `dfo`:

```
NE001  NE004
 2       2
```

I have tried `dfo <- df[,which(names(df) == colSums(df==2))]` but do not work.

Some ideas?

Comment: I don't quite follow the qeustion/logic; you're comparing numbers with strings. Why should the first and fourth columns match here?

Comment: In this `df` example we have just one row. Then the sum of rows to each collumn can be `0` or `2`. I would like to subset the collumns which rows sum is = `2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you just trying to subset the columns that sum to 2? If so, you were close.  Here's an example with a small data frame.

```
(d <- data.frame(x = c(2, 0), y = c(1, 2), z = c(1, 1)))
#   x y z
# 1 2 1 1
# 2 0 2 1
```

Since `colSums(d) == 2` returns a logical vector, we can subset with that and the columns that are `TRUE` will be returned

```
colSums(d) == 2
#    x     y     z 
# TRUE FALSE  TRUE 
d[colSums(d) == 2]
#   x z
# 1 2 1
# 2 0 1
```